# How to add 2 hours to the wordpress time formed with current_time("mysql", false)?

Tags: mysql, date, date-time

How to add 2 hours to the wordpress time which has already been formed using `current_time("mysql", false)`?

Comment: Second param on that function is an integer, not a boolean.  Are you getting GMT result or is that is simply being ignored?

Comment: From the Codex:  If the optional second parameter is 1, the value returned represents the current GMT time. If 0 or no second parameter are set, the value returned represents the local time for the timezone declared in the blog's Timezone setting on the General Settings page.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to add two hours to the local time for the timezone declared...

Comment: ahaaaa, General Settings, great!!!

Comment: please make this an answer, so that I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WordPress `current_time()` returns the current time in the format specified in the first parameter.  In your example code, this is the `mysql` value.  The second parameter represents a timezone option.  The default returns the local time for the timezone specified on the site's Settings > General page, or GMT depending on the value supplied when calling the function.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time

If time mathematics are still required, using the PHP `strtotime()` function is useful for this:

```
$now = current_time( 'mysql' ); 
echo 'It is currently: ' . $now . '<br>';
$later = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $now ) + 7200 ); //7200 seconds = 2 hours
echo 'In 2 hours it will be: ' . $later;
```

Comment: So you think that $later now - per your explanation - has the correct format for insertion to Wordpress DB?

Comment: That depends.  The date is just a string until a portion of code treats it as a date, right?  You can store the date in any format as long as you handle it properly when querying the DB.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't say anything about insertion to database, so I wouldn't know how to do it. It's a matter for another question though.